# Why is my composer command not working in subdirectories on a 1and1 webhosting server?

Tags: terminal, composer-php, typo3, webserver, web-hosting

I'm in the process of building a TYPO3 website on a webserver hosted by 1and1 ionos. I need to install TYPO3 via composer, so I installed composer to this webserver first. It seemed to work fine and I was able to do a composer reuqire to install TYPO3 to a new directory (named: typo3-composer) within the root of the server.

But for some reason I have two problems now:

1. Within the root directory of my server I cannot run the "composer xx" command. It only works using the prefix "php composer xx"
2. In my subdirectory typo3-composer (the one I installed TYPO3 into) I cannot run ANY composer command. Terminal simply says command composer not found.

What I did so far:

1. Install composer

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/bin/php8.0-cli
```

2.Start composer

```
/usr/bin/php8.0-cli composer.phar
```

3.Rename file

```
mv composer.phar composer
```

4.Tried to move the file to any directory (usr/local/bin) of the $PATHvariable to make composer globally accessible. This failed because all of those directories are read-only. So i made the file executable

```
chmod +x composer
```

5.And added the current path to the system's $PATH variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:$PWD
```

I'm pretty sure this is a very basic logial mistake. Where do I have to execute the composer install command and where do I have to put the composer file so that I can use the command from every directory?

(PS: I did set the PHP Version of the Shell to php 8.0 already so I don't have to use /usr/bin/php8.0-cli all the time)

Comment: Why do you need to run Composer on any other system than your own local development machine?

Comment: What would be the alternative? Developing everything on my local machine and then uploading it to the server? I'm very new to this but I was told things could get complicated this way. Or what did you mean?

Comment: Yes, that would be the usual way to work on such a project. Build your application on any system under your own control, deploy the artifact with the parts neccessary to run the application to the production server

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll try using it locally now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your well formulated question which I'd like to answer the following:

If you would like to (really) execute Composer on the remote host<sup>1</sup>, you already have the answer albeit you might not be aware of it. To quote from your very own question:

> It only works using the prefix "php composer xx"

This is fine and how PHP works on the command-line. However as you have noticed it depends on the directory you're in (the *working direcory*). Not for the command (`php`) but for the file you command `php(1)` to execute: "`composer`".

Some more context if it helps: The first operand of the `php` command you entered, "`composer`", is the path to the file you want `php(1)` to execute.

So when:

```
user@host:~$ php composer info
...
```

works and you then change the directory and it doesn't any longer:

```
user@host:~$ cd typo3-composer
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ php composer info
Could not open input file: composer
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ echo $?
1
```

then replacing `composer` with the actual path of it should work:

```
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ php ../composer info
...
```

before actually running `php(1)`, you can also make use of the `file(1)` command to check first if a file exists and of what type it is:

Not existing file:

```
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ file composer
composer: cannot open `composer' (No such file or directory)
```

Existing "composer" file (with executable bits set):

```
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ file ../composer
../composer: a /usr/bin/env php script executable (binary data)
```

Composer phar (even with no executable bits):

```
user@host:~/typo3-composer$ file ../composer
../composer: a /usr/bin/env php script executable (binary data)
```

Composer is just a PHP file (sort-of, it is a PHP archive "phar") and the idiom to execute it under the name `composer` is not really necessary. The path (absolute or relative to your currend working directory "PWD"<sup>2</sup>) suffices. If you take a look in the Composer documentation for example, you find the following idiom:

```
php composer.phar <options>|<operands>...
```

TLDR: Composer works regardless how you invoke it, be it `composer`, `php composer.phar` or similar. The `php(1)` command only needs a pathname of the PHP file to execute, be it `composer.phar` or one of the typo3 command-line scripts (to give a different example).

---

1. As user [*Nico Haase*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase) already has pointed out, there is no inherent requirement to execute `composer(1)` on the remote host.

   Composer interacts with the wide-area-network (WAN, also: WWW, internet) to download files and applies the result to the working directory (project directory), more specifically the *vendor-dir* (vendor directory, "`vendor`" relative to the `composer.json` configuration file by default).

   You normally then afterwards *deploy* that (local) project to the remote host.  There is no requirement at all to do the dependency resolution on the remote host, quite the opposite: bring the work near to yourself so that you can much faster deal with any problems that may arise and make the deployment step dead simple (e.g. a single, simple transaction).  Remote machines go offline, network connection may get lost in the middle and you may also need to (or want to) fully replace the remote host occasionally. All you should need to do is to re-deploy the project, not configuring remote systems and run commands there interactively.  Life is too short for that.

   Now the Typo3 project might have thought otherwise (which would not be very user-friendly if you allow me the comment, but I know the typo3 folks are user-friendly for real) then you may go through additional hurdles, however those are less related to Composer (and how you invoke it) but more to Typo3 (then, if at all).  But, as you don't present Typo3 as an issue in your question, I'm pretty sure you can just do the "Composer work" locally in your own shell which has the benefit that you can configure Composer and how you invoke it to your liking without the requirement to do this only short and half at best on every remote host you may come in contact with.
2. > **PWD**
   >
   > This variable shall represent an absolute pathname of the current working directory. It shall not contain any components that are dot or dot-dot. The value is set by the [*cd*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html) utility, and by the [*sh*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html) utility during initialization. *[[from]](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03)*

Comment: Perfectly explained, thank you so much!! Was thinking into the wrong direction... I was tought to use composer on the remote server and I didn't question it once. It can get way too complicated though. I'll be using it locally now!

Comment: Yes, it's far more easy to make things complicated when starting remote. That's just part of the reasoning I tried to make visible: Locally you can just better try things out and learn about them. Great feedback! @Doreen